# How to run function for specific time and sleep for a specific time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, period

I want to run `calculateSomething` function for a specific period of time, for example for `1 minute` which this function receive messages from `MQTT` protocol. After 1 minute, this function will sleep or stop receiving data from `MQTT` for `1 minute`, then start to run again.

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    calculateSomething(topic, message);
})


function calculateSomething(top, param) { 
    let graph = new Graph();
    if(top === 'togenesis') {
        graph.addEdgetogenesis(param.toString())

    } else if (top === 'DAG'){
        graph.addEdge(param.toString())  
    }
}
```

I have tried `setInterval()` but it keep run the function repeatly but I don't want to repeat the function because it is in real time. I also have tried `setTimeout()` but this only delay for the first time.

Any ideas please how could solve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with inbound messages in the minute when you're sleeping?  Just ignore them?  Queue them for processing later?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I want the algorithm do other things in this 1 minute and in the mean time the data is queued to be processed later.

Comment: Well, the answer you accepted does not queue the data to be processed later, it just ignores any data that arrives during the 1 minute period of rest.

Comment: could you help me how to do that? any hints please ?

Comment: What is the real purpose of the 1 minute pause in processing? I feel like I need to know what you're really trying to accomplish to know what implementation to best suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the execution of your function is subordinated by a boolean variable that I have named `start` which serves to keep the function operational (start = true) or not (start = false). The `setInterval` cycles for one minute and alternates the state of the boolean variable `start`.

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    calculateSomething(topic, message);
})

var start = true;

setInterval(function(){
    if(start){
        start = false;
    } else {
        start = true;
    }
}, 60000); //1 minute

function calculateSomething(top, param) { 
    if(start){ //the function is executed only if start is true
        let graph = new Graph();
        if(top === 'togenesis') {
            graph.addEdgetogenesis(param.toString())

        } else if (top === 'DAG'){
            graph.addEdge(param.toString())  
        }
    }
}
```